# JavaScript multidimensional-array check if typeof is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

If you create a multidimensional-array:

```
var ThisArray = [];
ThisArray["a"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] = "This is a string.";
```

How can you check if `ThisArray["a"]["w"]["c"]` for example is defined. Right now I'm doing this:

```
if (typeof ThisArray !== 'undefined') {
    if (typeof ThisArray["a"] !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof ThisArray["a"]["w"] !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof ThisArray["a"]["w"]["c"] !== 'undefined') {

                // ThisArray["a"]["w"]["c"] is defined!

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this better and cleaner?

Comment: An array should have number indices, not strings. Did you mean to use an object `{}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
if (typeof ThisArray?.["a"]?.["w"]?.["c"] !== 'undefined') {
   // ThisArray["a"]["w"]["c"] is defined!
}
```

As noted in the comments, this is a relatively new language feature, and is not supported by older browsers. See [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Note that this requires Firefox 74+ or Chrome 80+

Comment: This is a great solution, just make sure this meets the browser compatibility requirement for your project: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional chaining.
the optional chaining operator enables  simple way to access values through connected objects when it's possible that a reference or function may be undefined or null, hence, protecting you from getting null exception on null/undefined objects.

```js
var ThisArray = [];
ThisArray["a"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] = "This is a string.";

console.log(ThisArray.a.b.c?.d?.e);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect place to use optional chaining!

You can do so like this:

```js
if (typeof ThisArray.a?.b?.c !== 'undefined') {
  console.log(`ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] is defined!`);
}
```

Here's a full demo:

```js
var ThisArray = [];
ThisArray["a"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"] = [];
ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] = "This is a string.";

if (typeof ThisArray.a?.b?.c !== 'undefined') {
  console.log(`ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] is defined!`);
  console.log(`ThisArray.a.w.c === "${ThisArray.a.b.c}"`)
} else {
  console.log(`ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"] is NOT defined!`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go with try catch

```js
var thirdDimensionValue = null;
try{
thirdDimensionValue = ThisArray["a"]["b"]["c"]
}
catch{
thirdDimensionValue = null
}
if(thirdDimensionValue){
console.log("value exist")
}
else{
console.log("No value exist in the property")
}
```